# Response issue in FuelSDK in c# for exact TargetAPI

Tags: marketing-cloud, c#

I am getting this error.

An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to https://webservice.s7.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx.
This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol.
This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server
(possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.

I am simply running this code using FuelSDK in c# for Exact Target.

DateTime filterDate = new DateTime(2011, 1, 15, 13, 0, 0);

```
        Console.WriteLine("--- Testing OpenEvent ---");
        ET_Client myclient = new ET_Client();

        Console.WriteLine("Retrieve Filtered OpenEvents with GetMoreResults");
        ET_OpenEvent oe = new ET_OpenEvent();
        oe.AuthStub = myclient;
        oe.SearchFilter = new SimpleFilterPart() { Property = "EventDate", SimpleOperator = SimpleOperators.greaterThan, DateValue = new DateTime[] { filterDate } };
        oe.Props = new string[] { "SendID", "SubscriberKey", "EventDate", "Client.ID", "EventType", "BatchID", "TriggeredSendDefinitionObjectID", "PartnerKey" };
        GetReturn oeGet = oe.Get();

        Console.WriteLine("Get Status: " + oeGet.Status.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Message: " + oeGet.Message.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Code: " + oeGet.Code.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Results Length: " + oeGet.Results.Length);
        Console.WriteLine("MoreResults: " + oeGet.MoreResults.ToString());
        // Since this could potentially return a large number of results, we do not want to print the results
        foreach (ET_OpenEvent openEvent in oeGet.Results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SubscriberKey: " + openEvent.SubscriberKey + ", EventDate: " + openEvent.EventDate.ToString());
        }

        while (oeGet.MoreResults)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Continue Retrieve Filtered OpenEvents with GetMoreResults");
            oeGet = oe.GetMoreResults();
            Console.WriteLine("Get Status: " + oeGet.Status.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Message: " + oeGet.Message.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Code: " + oeGet.Code.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Results Length: " + oeGet.Results.Length);
            Console.WriteLine("MoreResults: " + oeGet.MoreResults.ToString());
        }
```

First time I got results with some Open events . when I run it time 2nd time I m getting 0 result for same code. some time I got error describe earlier in this section. agin after some hour later i got result, next time again 0 result.

What is the issue ,please help.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the code : oe.GetSinceLastBatch = false;

follow this for more info : [Fuel SDK - Subsequent ET_BounceEvent() calls with same parameters returns empty Results](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/53981/fuel-sdk-subsequent-et-bounceevent-calls-with-same-parameters-returns-empty?rq=1)